# How to keep the capability of users and disable Gutenberg editor in WordPress?

Tags: php, functions, user-roles, block-editor, capabilities

I disabled Gutenberg web builder/ editor using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false' );
```

Somehow this impacted contributor's capability to submit post for review, now contributor's posts are not asking any approval. I tried to remove the capability manually, by writing this code,

```
$role->remove_cap( 'publish_posts' );
```

but this code also has no effect at all.

It seems a WordPress bug, any suggestion?? It's showing the same results with https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ plugin too.

[image]

Comment: "contributor's capability to submit post for review" this is not a core functionality. What plugin are you using for it? Have you contacted their support?

Comment: create one user, assign role to contributor, when they will write a post or commit a revision, that will go to admin for approval (core functionality), now disable gutenberg web builder, now when they will create a post or will commit any revision, it will be published immediately (bug), I am not using any plugin till now

Comment: To my knowledge there is no approval process in WordPress. Do you mean that they create drafts and admin will publish these?

Comment: yes, kind of, check attached image, I have updated my question

Comment: @kero there is sir, may be you are not aware of, not a big task, not all deal with all the roles, you can check/ test this by yourself, it's 5 mins work only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these lines in your 'functions.php', it will work

```
//if not gutenberg reapprove posts
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 're_aprove', '99', 2 );
function re_aprove( $data, $postarr ) {
    //check if current user is not admin
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        if ( 'publish' === $data['post_status'] ) {
            $data['post_status'] = 'pending';
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: worked, thanks a lot!!

Comment: keep coding & keep learning :)